# Multiple input box excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, input, multiple-columns

Right now I've been using multiple Input boxes to get user input for a couple of strings i need:

```
 Dim U As String
 Dim P As String

U = Application.InputBox("Enter Username", "Username", Type:=1))
P = Application.InputBox("Enter Pwd", "pwd", Type:=1))
```

etc ..

Is there any way I can make an input box with multiple inputs or some sort of multiple input into an Excel worksheet using VBA?

Comment: UserForms are the way to go, per the answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create a user form:

http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-userform-excel-vba.html

Comment: Bare Links are not answers :) This should be a comment.